# How to pass parameter to the redirected page on ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, parameter-passing

I am trying to display a grid div using ng-repeat. It will display three grids each with a SensorID passed as a parameter. Now, I have created a ng-click to redirect to another page on click of each one of the div's. On redirect, I also want to pass the corresponding SensorID of each div.

I have already tried to pass the parameter to the ng-click function. I am getting the clicked SensorID in console on ng-click, but I am not able to display it in the redirected page.

I am getting something like this where 404273 & 404279 are the SensorID.
http://localhost:4400/index.html#!/WaterDoorMotion/404273 
http://localhost:4400/index.html#!/WaterDoorMotion/404279

PS: In the code, mainCtrl is my main controller where AngularJS is loaded.

```
/*----Angular JS----*/ 
vm.GetWaterDoorMotion = function () {
        var WaterDoorMotionURL = url + 'sensors/waterdoormotion';
        $http.get(WaterDoorMotionURL).then(function (response) {
            vm.WaterDoorMotion = response.data;
 });
    }

 vm.RedirectToWaterDoorMotion = function (SensorID) {
        vm.Sensorid = SensorID
        $location.path('/WaterDoorMotion/' + vm.Sensorid);
    }

/*----HTML----*/
//First Page
 <div  ng-repeat="Sensor in mainCtrl.WaterDoorMotion" ng-click="mainCtrl.RedirectToWaterDoorMotion(Sensor.SensorID)"
<span>{{Sensor.SensorName}}</span><p>{{Sensor.SensorID}}</p></div>

//Redirected Page
<div>
    <span>SensorID : {{mainCtrl.Sensorid}}</span>
</div>
```

[Div's with SensorID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aysr.png)

Comment: You can pass sesnsor id in query params i.e http://localhost:4400/index.html#!/WaterDoorMotion?id=404273 and then extract it in your redirected page

Comment: I have tried this way, but i am not able to extract the SensorID in redirected page. Can you provide with some helpful code ? Thank you.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass sesnsor id in query params i.e `localhost:4400/index.html#!/WaterDoorMotion?id=404273`  and then extract it in your redirected page i.e

```
var sensorId = new RegExp('[\?&]id=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);//RegExp for extracting
      var cId = "";
      if(sensorId != undefined){
        if(sensorId.length > 1){
          cId = sensorId[1];
        }
      }
console.log("cId",cId);
```

Comment: Sure. Thank you for the help.